# Why my LSTM model always start a prediction with the same pattern?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I want to find out why my LSTM NN always starts the forecast with a peak.

This is my model: [image: Model]

And those are some Predictions:[image]

If you check that the red line always starts with a peak, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Have you tried with a different weight initialization?

Comment: Not yet, do you think it's a matter of weight initialization? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you tell us the what the data is about?

Comment: The blue signal come from a sensor that measure strain.
The green signal is an ideal syntetic signal produced by a montecarlo simulation. 
My goal il to transform the input data into something like the green line, so, using a supervised approach, I'm trying to transform the blue signal into the green one